# Why is logically wrong in this c program code for copying a directory?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to create a copy program which takes source and destination directories and copies directories from source to destination. The case where both directory names are file paths, it works. For the case where source is a file and destination is a directory, it works. However for the case of both source and directories to be directories, it does not work properly, not even the simple case of non-multilevel level directories. . Please suggest editions.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void copyfile(char source[],char destination[]);
void traverse(char source[],char destination[]);
int isdir(char path[]);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if(argc<3)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Improper syntax\n");
        printf("\t./copy [source path] [destination path]\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    char *source=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(argv[1])+1);
    char *destination=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(argv[2])+1);

    strcpy(source,argv[1]);
    strcpy(destination,argv[2]);

    if(isdir(source)&&!isdir(destination))
    {
        printf("Destination cannot be a file\n");
        exit(0);
    }   
    if(isdir(source)&&isdir(destination))
        traverse(source,destination);
    else copyfile(source,destination);

    return 0;
}

void copyfile(char source[],char destination[])
{
    int c;

    if(!isdir(source)&&isdir(destination))
    {
        char *fname=strrchr(source,'/');
        if(realloc(destination,strlen(destination)+strlen(source)+2)==NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory reallocation error\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        strcat(destination,fname);  
    }

    FILE *f1,*f2;
    f1=fopen(source,"r");
    f2=fopen(destination,"w");

    if(f1==NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exists");
        return;
    }

    if(f2==NULL)
    {
        printf("File copying error: Directory may or may not exist\n");
        return;
    }

    while((c=fgetc(f1))!=EOF)
        fputc(c,f2);

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    return;
}

int isdir(char path[])
{
    struct stat dir;
    stat(path,&dir);
    if(S_ISREG(dir.st_mode))
        return 0;
    if(S_ISDIR(dir.st_mode))
        return 1;
    printf("The source is not a file, neither a dir\n");
    exit(0);
}

void traverse(char source[],char destination[])
{   
    char *fname=strrchr(source,'/');

    char *tdest=(char *)malloc(strlen(destination)+strlen(fname)+1+6);

    strcpy(tdest,"mkdir ");
    strcat(tdest,destination);
    strcat(tdest,fname);
    system(tdest);
    if(realloc(destination,(strlen(destination)+strlen(fname))*sizeof(char)+1)==NULL)
    {
        printf("Destination rellocaion pointer inturrupted\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    strcat(destination,fname);  

    DIR *d1;
    if((d1=opendir(source))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Source access inturrupted\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    struct dirent *cwd;

    struct stat dir;
    while((cwd=readdir(d1))!=NULL)
    {   
        char *tsource=(char *)malloc((strlen(source)+strlen(cwd->d_name))*sizeof(char)+2);
        stat(cwd->d_name,&dir);
        if(S_ISDIR(dir.st_mode))
        {
            if(strcmp(cwd->d_name,".")==0||strcmp(cwd->d_name,"..")==0)continue;        

            traverse(source,destination);
        }

        strcpy(tsource,source);
        strcat(tsource,"/");
        strcat(tsource,cwd->d_name);
        copyfile(tsource,destination);
    }

    closedir(d1);       
    return;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always equal to `1`

Comment: `realloc(destination,(strlen(destination)+strlen(fname))*sizeof(char)+1)` --> `(destination = realloc(destination,(strlen(destination)+strlen(fname))*sizeof(char)+1))`

Comment: `stat(path,&dir);` You are not checking the return value here. It could be -1 ...

Answer (score 2):

You are failing with [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc): its return value must be assigned (usually re-assigned) to a pointer.

```
destination = realloc(destination, (strlen(destination)+strlen(fname))*sizeof(char)+1);

if (destination == NULL)
{
    printf("Destination rellocaion pointer inturrupted\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Take note that all call to malloc should avoid to cast returned value and all returned values must be NULL checked.

---

As @Quentin correctly commented, be aware that if `realloc` fails the memory pointed by destination is leaked: address of that memory is lost. So to do it very safely you can you a temp var:

```
char *temp = realloc(destination, (strlen(destination)+strlen(fname))*sizeof(char)+1);

if (temp == NULL)
{
    printf("Destination rellocaion pointer inturrupted\n");
    exit(0);
}

destination = temp;
```

---

Takes also note that all `malloc`ated chunks must be freed, even if OS will free it for you when program terminates. It is the best way to code and to avoid future memory leaks problem: `free` the memory as far as that specific memory is not more used.

Comment: Caution : if `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`, you leak the memory pointed by `destination`.

Comment: @Quentin. I'll add a note. BTW the OP code exit the program in case of `realloc` fails.

Comment: @LPs: Also, to be completely correct, you have to call `free(destination)` before exiting/returning in case `temp == NULL`, otherwise you are leaking memory. The "old" memory after a failed `realloc` is still there and has to be freed, too.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Formally correct, but OP code is exiting the program, so the memory is freed.

Comment: @LPs: Yes, but if you run such a program through a tool like valgrind, it will report memory leaks. It's better not to rely on the OS freeing up memory.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev I totally agree. I edited because actually OP is not freeing a single `malloc`ated mem in the whole code.

Comment: If `realloc` succeeds, but cannot extend the current allocation, the newly allocated memory is inaccessible, since the returned pointer has not been saved. It is thus NEVER correct to ignore the return value from `realloc`, since there's no guarantee that after `foo = realloc(bar, new_size);` the condition `foo == bar` holds, even if `foo` is not NULL.

Comment: @Vatine: Correct, but I've never encountered `(void) realloc(bar, new_size);`, whereas `foo = realloc(foo, new_size);` is much more common and is still erratic. A more common problem is when some pointers to the old region are kept and not updated after each `realloc`.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev OP's original code actually has `if (realloc(...) == NULL)` which is almost exactly "throwing away the pointer returned by realloc".